# How to show image on notification using aws amplify push notification in react native app?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, aws-lambda, aws-amplify, aws-pinpoint

I have integrated the push notification using `@aws-amplify/push notification`. Now I have received the notification without the image, but I want to show the image.

Can anyone please help?

Comment: how are you sending the image parameter? and image should be less than 1 mb

Comment: yes image size less than 1 mb, can you show how i handle in client side?

Comment: still my problem not solved so please help anyone

Answer (score 0):

- To do this, enter the URL for the image or video file in the media box.The URL must be publicly accessible.